# Solr: create a multivalued field from tokens

Tags: solr

I have a solr field that contains a list of dates written as a string where dates are separated by spaces :

e.g. "important_date": "2015-01-25T02:21:32Z 2015-01-10T10:30:32Z"

This field has text_ws as type, so I can query this field using only one of the date, but still the "dates" are string and I want them to be dates.

So, what I really want is a multiValued date (_dts) field

e.g. date_dts = [2015-01-25T02:21:32Z  ,  2015-01-10T10:30:32Z]

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using a multivalued field and a custom UpdateRequestProcessor with processAdd() overriden.

There, you should remove and get the incoming value (the list or the compound string) in the SolrInputDocument, split the dates and re-add them one by one using addField(name, value)